# Magento Migrate only, really only customers data?

Tags: magento2.3, data-migration

is there somebody out there having a working solution for migrating only customer data (name, addresses, city, birthday etc.) from 1.9.3.7 to 2.3.5?
I tried all possible solutions mentioned in other questions here, but none of them worked. EIther nothing imported or not only customers data.
I did aslo not find a real good explanation about the use of mapping files.
So, I am a little bit frustrated and as well, I do not really want to pay 400$ for module doing it (maybe).
So, does somebody have the working solutions and could provide this?
Best regards,
Chequille

Answer (score 1):

simply export customers from Magento 1 into csv file.

then create 1 customer in Magento 2 and export in csv file.

open files and adjust field names and data.

delete that test customer in Magento 2.

import ready csv files into Magento 2.

done.

Answer (score 0):

Before migrating data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3, you need to create a fresh new site on Magento 2.3.5 then use an automated migration tool to migrate directly all data from your old store to the new one with a high level of security and accuracy. You can check the price that depends on how many entities you want to transfer to Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for your suggestions.
In the meantime, I found the easiest  way to do it, because it is possible with the migration tool as described in some questions answered here.

The issue why it did not work on my site was "missing memory". Somewhere here I found, that somebody called the migrate module like:

php -d memory_limit=10G bin/magento migrate:data --auto .......

Using the additional parameter memory_limit made it workin on my site. Strange, because I did not get any error message, but message "migrate successfull". Result was "nothing imported".

So at the end, working solution for only migrate customers is:

In config.xml define:

```
<steps mode="data">
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
<options>
    <customer_map_file>[your path to map-customer.xml]</customer_map_file>
    <customer_document_groups_file>[your path to customer-document-groups.xml]</customer_document_groups_file>
    <customer_attribute_groups_file>[your path to customer-attribute-groups.xml]</customer_attribute_groups_file>
```